# Trouble fetching all the names from a webpage with messy layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've written a script to parse all the mobile shop names from a webpage. When I run my script I an get a very few of them. How can I get all the names from that page where last name at this moment is `Parkway Mobile Home Park - Alabama`?

[webpage link](http://www.chattelmortgage.net/Alabama_mobile_home_parks.html)

This is what I've tried so far with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "replace with above link"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
items = soup.select_one("table tr")
name = '\n'.join([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("td p strong") if "alabama" in item.text.lower()])
print(name)
```

Output are like:

```
Roberts Trailer Park - Alabama
Cloverleaf Trailer Park - Alabama
Longview Mobile Home Park - Alabama
```

Comment: Would you give us the url so we can try ourselves ?

Comment: Take a look above to find the link which is already there.

Comment: sorry I didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `html.parser` instead of `lxml`. Also, instead of using `select_one('table tr')`, try using `find_all('strong')`. You'll also need to remove extra spaces and carriage returns.

The following code will return the expected (491) records:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.chattelmortgage.net/Alabama_mobile_home_parks.html"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('strong')
name = '\n'.join([re.sub('\s{2,}', ' ', re.sub('[\r\n]', '', item.text)).strip() for item in items if 'alabama' in item.text.lower()])
print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The html of the page is very poor so it's quite ugly but that works :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.chattelmortgage.net/Alabama_mobile_home_parks.html"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'tablebg, tableBorder'})
print([item.text.strip()  for item in table.find_all("strong") if "alabama" in item.text.lower()])
```